# Why is $\int_{\Gamma } f \left ( z \right )dz=0?$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, holomorphic-functions

$\Gamma$  refers to a once continuous counterclockwise closed circle with center $\xi =2$ and with a positive radius $r=3$. I need to determine the following integral $\frac{1}{z+2}$.

Why is $\int_{\Gamma } f \left ( z \right )dz=0?$

I know  that is something connected with holomorphic function and line integral but still can't find the rules how to calculate integral of function when I have specific value of radius and center?

If someone could help me, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?  First you can set up the path (or line) integral easily in terms of a parameterization of the circle of radius $3$ centered at $\xi = 2 + 0i$.  Then you have to do the integration.

Answer (score 1):

$\log(z+2)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,-2]$ (which contains the circle in question) and is an antiderivative of $1/(z+2)$ in this region. To evaluate the integral, you simply subtract the values of the antiderivative at the endpoints. Since this is a closed curve, the endpoints are the same, and we get $0$ for the integral

Answer (score 0):

The only singularity of $f$ is at $z = -2$, which is not in $\Gamma$ and neither in its interior. So $f$ is holomorphic there. Since $\Gamma$ is closed, by [Cauchy-Goursat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) follows that $\int_\Gamma f(z)\,{\rm d}z = 0$.

Comment: It seems that the OP might know this, but wants to carry out the integration explicitly (or was assigned to do so).

Comment: But how do I know that it's not in it?

Comment: Because the radius is $r=3$, the singularity is in $-2$, and $|\xi - (-2)| = |2+2| = 4 > 3 = r$.